# How to dynamically load images in a layer using actionscript

Tags: image, flash, loading

I used the below code to load images that are present in my library:

```
Create_Image_With_Description();

function Create_Image_With_Description():Void {
this.createEmptyMovieClip("imageHolder", 600); 
// Put Here Images URoL 
imageHolder.loadMovie("Symbol 1"); 
// Position 
imageHolder._x = 0;
imageHolder._y = 0; 
// Size 
imageHolder._xscale = 210;
imageHolder._yscale = 215;
// Example: my_mc.createTextField(instanceName:String, depth:Number, x:Number,
y:Number,width:Number, height:Number) : Void 
this.createTextField("description1Field",1,10,203,120,20); 
// Put Here Images description 
description1Field.text = "Resident Evil: Afterlife";
}
```

Here symbol 1 is the image that i've converted into a symbol. When i tried running this i got an error saying "Error opening URL 'file:///E|/Symbol 1'".
I've also tried giving imageHolder.loadMovie("img1.jpg"); But still it didn't worked. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing these lines:

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("imageHolder", 1000); 
// Put Here Images URL 
this.attachMovie("img1", "img1", {_x:100, _y:100});
```